# Question on the Gateaux derivative (being the principal part of a system of PDEs)

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, gateaux-derivative

Let me start with a disclaimer. This is the first time ever dealing with Gateaux derivative, hence my knowledge around this topic is poor.

As I was going through [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.06878), I got stuck in the following part:

[image]

Here the function $f$ is given by: $f(u_1)=-u_1(u_1-\alpha)(u_1-1)$. In my understanding, $A_\rho$ is simply the linear part of $(2.2)$. How come and in addition represents the Gateaux derivative of $F_\rho$? In any case, I see no differentiation with respect to anything here.

I'm having a hard time getting my head around this one. Could you please share more details on why $A_\rho=dF_\rho(0)$? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: After the comment I received, I realized that I certainly did not phrase my question correctly. I do not see the second equality in $(2.3)$, not the first one. I get that $A_\rho$ is simply defined. But in my understanding, the matrix in $(2.3)$ is only the linear part of $(2.2)$, without any differentiation involving somehow. But then again, in $(2.3)$, it is claimed that it is the Gateuax derivative...

Comment: This seems to be just a definition of $A_\rho$, not a derivation of $A_\rho$. $A_\rho$ is defined to be the derivative of $F_\rho$ at $(u_1,u_2)=0$.

Comment: @daw Many thanks for the comment. I just edited my post because I realized that my actual question was not stated clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of $F_\rho$ is
$$
F_\rho(u_1,u_2) = \pmatrix{ \Delta u_1 + −u_1(u_1−\alpha)(u_1−1)- u_2 \\ \epsilon u_1 + \epsilon\gamma u_2},
$$
so that its Gateaux derivative **at** $(u_1,u_2)=0$ is the operator in block form
$$
F'_\rho(0,0) = \pmatrix{ \Delta  + \alpha\ id & -id \\ \epsilon id &  \epsilon\gamma\ id}.
$$
here, $\alpha \ id = f'_\rho(0)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. But as I said, since I have no previous experience with Gateaux derivatives, I struggle a bit to see the implication. What is $f^\prime_\rho(0)$ and why here is just the identity matrix? Why $\Delta$ was not affected by differentation? Do you have any good reference to suggest?